# How do you create on Xamarin a function that does something differently depending on the platform?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm developing an App for Android, iOS and UWP. At the moment I want to do something that unfortunately works differently on every platform from a ViewModel that's called by the crossplatform Xamarin.forms.

How do I create a function or class from that ViewModel that runs different Platform specific code depending on the platform that currently build?

Comment: Will it use platform specific code or just different logic?

Comment: @FCin Platform specific code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a service called `DependencyService` which allows you to register multiple implementations of an interface and it automatically returns proper implementation based on current environment.

You define interface in your common project, e.g.:

```
public interface IPrinter
{
    void Print();
}
```

And in each project you create different implementation. You also have to mark it with `[assembly(typeof(YOUR_CLASS_NAME))]` attribute.

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(AndroidPrinter))]
namespace MyApp.Android
{
    public class AndroidPrinter : IPrinter
    {
        public class Print()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your common project, in ViewModel, you can call:

```
public void ViewModelFooMethod()
{
    DependencyService.Get<IPrinter>().Print();
}
```

More about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Answer (score 1):

This should be your `if` `else` statement in your `ViewModel` class based on `Platform`. You can append one more `else` block that would be default for `UWP`

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    //ios
}
else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
    //android
}
```

One more way is there to get it is by using *Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo* package from NuGet Package manager. Import

`using Plugin.DeviceInfo;`

Get `Platform` info like this

```
CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform.ToString();
```